# Lists with wildcards cause Generic voodoo error

Tags: java, generics, generic-list, generic-collections

Does anyone know why the following code does not compile? Neither add() nor addAll() works as expected. Removing the "? extends" part makes everything work, but then I would not be able to add subclasses of Foo.

```
 List<? extends Foo> list1 = new ArrayList<Foo>();
 List<? extends Foo> list2 = new ArrayList<Foo>();

 /* Won't compile */
 list2.add( new Foo() ); //error 1
 list1.addAll(list2);    //error 2
```

error 1:

IntelliJ says:

```
add(capture<? extends Foo>) in List cannot be applied to add(Foo)
```

The compiler says:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : method addAll(java.util.List<capture#692 of ? extends Foo>)
location: interface java.util.List<capture#128 of ? extends Foo>
```

error 2:

IntelliJ gives me

```
addAll(java.util.Collection<? extends capture<? extends Foo>>) in List cannot be applied to addAll(java.util.List<capture<? extends Foo>>)
```

Whereas the compiler just says

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : method addAll(java.util.List<capture#692 of ? extends Foo>)
location: interface java.util.List<capture#128 of ? extends Foo>
        list1.addAll(list2);
```

Comment: Please explain why you use <? extends Foo>, instead just Foo. In explaining that, maybe things will get clear.

Comment: Hey, Ingo. Excellent point, and one that might have created better/more accurate answers earlier on. I was confused by method parameters using wildcards to accept subtypes, and thought I needed to use the <? extends Foo> notation to be able to add subtypes to the collection. Myers and Paulo (below) helped to get why that is not necessary (or right). Good comment - thanks!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

(I assume here that `Bar` and `Baz` are both subtypes of `Foo`.)

`List<? extends Foo>` means **a list of elements of some type, which is a subtype of Foo, but we don't know which type**. Examples of such lists would be a `ArrayList<Foo>`, a `LinkedList<Bar>` and a `ArrayList<Baz>`.

As we don't know which subtype is the type parameter, we can't put `Foo` objects into it, neither `Bar` or `Baz` objects. But we still know that the type parameter is a subtype of `Foo`, so every element already in the list (and which we can get from the list) must be a `Foo` object, so we can use  `Foo f = list.get(0);` and similar things.

Such a list can only be used for taking elements out of the list, not to adding elements at all (apart from `null`, but I don't know if the compiler actually allows this).

A `List<Foo>` on the other hand allows adding any object which is a `Foo` object - and as `Bar` and `Baz` are subtypes of `Foo`, all `Bar` and `Baz` objects are `Foo` objects, so they can be added, too.

Comment: Thanks, Paulo! The linked answer from Michael Myers was also very to the point, but your answer did not require a detour :)

Answer (score 29):

Remember PECS: [Producer Extends, Consumer Super](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs/2723538#2723538).

Since you are trying to add items to list2, it is a consumer and cannot be declared as `List<? extends Foo>`. But then you are using list2 as a producer also when you add it to list1. Therefore, list2 is both a producer and a consumer and must be a `List<Foo>`.

list1, as a pure consumer, can be a `List<? super Foo>`.

Comment: Thanks for your help - the PECS answer on the linked page is excellent! Upvoting for your linked answer, but awarding Paulo the credit for the accepted answer, since it didn't requre a detour to be comprehensive :)

Answer (score 9):

They're errors. Lets modify your code, considering that `Bar` and `Baz` are two different types extending `Foo`:

```
List<? extends Foo> list1 = new ArrayList<Bar>();
List<? extends Foo> list2 = new ArrayList<Baz>();
```

If `list1.add(new Foo())` was allowed, you could add Foo instances in a collection containing Bar instances. This explains the first error.

If `list1.addAll(list2)` was allowed, all instances of Baz in list2 would be added to list1, which contains only Bar instances. This explains the second error.

Answer (score 4):

Let me try to explain in what case you might need to use `<? extend Classname>`.

So, lets say you have 2 classes:

```
class Grand {
    private String name;

    public Grand(String name) {
        this.setName(name);
    }

    public Grand() {
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Dad extends Grand {
    public Dad(String name) {
        this.setName(name);
    }

    public Dad() {
    }
}
```

And lets say you have 2 collections, each contains some Grands and some Dads:

```
    List<Dad> dads = new ArrayList<>();
    dads.add(new Dad("Dad 1"));
    dads.add(new Dad("Dad 2"));
    dads.add(new Dad("Dad 3"));


    List<Dad> grands = new ArrayList<>();
    dads.add(new Dad("Grandpa 1"));
    dads.add(new Dad("Grandpa 2"));
    dads.add(new Dad("Grandpa 3"));
```

Now, lets asume that we want to have collection, which will contain Grand or Dad objects:

```
        List<Grand> resultList;
        resultList = dads; // Error - Incompatable types List<Grand> List<Dad>
        resultList = grands;//Works fine
```

How we can avoid this? Simply use wildcard:

```
List<? extends Grand> resultList;
resultList = dads; // Works fine
resultList = grands;//Works fine
```

Notice, that you cant add new items in such (resultList) collection. For more information you can read about Wildcard and PECS conseption in Java

Comment: I don't' see any difference between `List<Dad> dads` and `List<Dad> grands`, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, maybe I misunderstood your question, but suposing:

```
public class Bar extends Foo{ }
```

this code:

```
List<Foo> list2 = new ArrayList<Foo>()
list2.add( new Bar() );
```

do not generate any error for me.

So, removing the wild card allows adding subclasses of Foo.

Comment: In the question, `List<? extends Foo>` is used as the variable type, not `List<Foo>` :-)

Comment: @Vivien: I know. What I state is that the wildcard can be removed for the code to compile.

Comment: And it will allow adding subclasses of Foo.