# How do I get all nodes in a parent in JavaFX?

Tags: java, recursion, javafx, javafx-8

In C# I found a method that was pretty sweet that allowed you to get all the descendants and all of THEIR descendants from a specified control.

I'm looking for a similar method for JavaFX.

I saw that the `Parent` class is what I want to work with since it is the class from which all Node classes that bear children are derived.

This is what I have so far (and I haven't really found anything on google with searches like "JavaFX get all nodes from a scene"):

```
public static ArrayList<Node> GetAllNodes(Parent root){
    ArrayList<Node> Descendents = new ArrayList<>();
    root.getChildrenUnmodifiable().stream().forEach(N -> {
        if (!Descendents.contains(N)) Descendents.add(N);
        if (N.getClass() == Parent.class) Descendents.addAll(
            GetAllNodes((Parent)N)
        );
    });
}
```

So how do I tell if N is a parent (or extended from a parent)? Am I doing that right? It doesn't seem to be working... It's grabbing all the nodes from the root (parent) node but not from the nodes with children in them. I feel like this is something that's probably got an answer to it but I'm just asking the question... wrong. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Maybe change the title from scene to parent?

Comment: please change the title, as Scene is not Parent

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
public static ArrayList<Node> getAllNodes(Parent root) {
    ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
    addAllDescendents(root, nodes);
    return nodes;
}

private static void addAllDescendents(Parent parent, ArrayList<Node> nodes) {
    for (Node node : parent.getChildrenUnmodifiable()) {
        nodes.add(node);
        if (node instanceof Parent)
            addAllDescendents((Parent)node, nodes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the extra method though? What is wrong with keeping it all in one method?

Comment: @Will It uses less memory because with the second method you don't have to create a new ArrayList every single time the method is called--you just add all the nodes to the same one. Just good programming practice.

Comment: @Will the performance is also faster because you avoid the many `arraycopy` operations that would occur if you were constantly merging lists together. Again, just good programming practice.

Comment: _performance is also faster_ Did you measure that? If not, it's nothing but a wild-wild guess :-)

Comment: @kleopatra You don't have to perform any testing to realize that n `add` operations + m `arraycopy` operations + m `new ArrayList()` operations (m > 0) will take longer to perform than n `add` operations + 0 `arraycopy` operations + 0 `new ArrayList()` operations, ceteris paribus. I'm sure it wouldn't make much of a difference at all unless you were working with huge numbers. But you're welcome to measure the difference yourself and then come back with something constructive to say :-)

Comment: _unless you were working with huge number_ exactly :-) So your performance argument is either beside any point in ui or you can prove - by measuring - that the number of copies in a typical ui context is near-enough to huge that it matters (very like not).

Answer (score 1):

I use this,

```
public class NodeUtils {

    public static <T extends Pane> List<Node> paneNodes(T parent) {
        return paneNodes(parent, new ArrayList<Node>());
    }

    private static <T extends Pane> List<Node> paneNodes(T parent, List<Node> nodes) {
        for (Node node : parent.getChildren()) {
            if (node instanceof Pane) {
                paneNodes((Pane) node, nodes);
            } else {
                nodes.add(node);
            }
        }

        return nodes;
    }
}
```

Usage,

```
List<Node> nodes = NodeUtils.paneNodes(aVBoxOrAnotherContainer);
```

This source code uses the references of the existing nodes. It does not clone them.

Comment: It will not find nodes inside a TitledPane even though they can have child nodes, as they are not Panes. But changing Pane to Region and using `getChildrenUnmodifiable()` instead of `getChildren()` seems to work

Answer (score 1):

This seems to get ALL nodes.
(In Kotlin)

```
fun getAllNodes(root: Parent): ArrayList<Node> {
    var nodes = ArrayList<Node>()
    fun recurseNodes(node: Node) {
        nodes.add(node)
        if(node is Parent)
            for(child in node.childrenUnmodifiable) {
                recurseNodes(child)
            }
    }
    recurseNodes(root)
    return nodes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add to Hans' answer, that you have to check if parent is a `SplitPane`. Because `SplitPane`s have an empty list using `getUnmodifiableChildren()`, you'll have to use `getItems()` instead. (I do not know if there are other parents that do not provide their children via `getUnmodifiableChildren()`. `SplitPane` was the first I found...)

Comment: Yeah there's quite a bunch. Including menus. It's a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this won't get subnodes for most container components. If you try a `TabPane` as parent, you'll find no children, but you can find tabs in it with `getTabs()`. The same is with `SplitPane` and other. So every container will require a specific approach.

You could use `node.lookupAll("*")`, but it also doesn't look inside.

The solution could be a "Prototype" pattern - creating a meta class with common interface of `getChildren()` method, which is realized in subclasses - one for each type.

Approach example is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17117677/1112963).

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
public class FXUtil {

    public static final List<Node> getAllChildren(final Parent parent) {
        final List<Node> result = new LinkedList<>();

        if (parent != null) {

            final List<Node> childrenLvl1 = parent.getChildrenUnmodifiable();
            result.addAll(childrenLvl1);

            final List<Node> childrenLvl2 =
                    childrenLvl1.stream()
                                .filter(c -> c instanceof Parent)
                                .map(c -> (Parent) c)
                                .map(FXUtil::getAllChildren)
                                .flatMap(List::stream)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
            result.addAll(childrenLvl2);
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```