# How to concatenate lists into one list

Tags: java, arraylist, concatenation

I have a list of values, some of which could be lists/collections or single values. In JavaScript notation it might look like:

```
const input = [1,2,[3,4], [5,6], 7];
```

and I want to get:

```
const concatenated = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
```

So I have this Java code:

```
      ArrayList<T> concatenated = new ArrayList<>();

      for (T v : input) {
        try{
          concatenated.addAll((Collection) v);
        }
        catch (Exception e1){
          try{
            concatenated.addAll((List) v);
          }
          catch (Exception e2){
            concatenated.add(v);
          }
        }

     }
```

but that code seems pretty terrible to me. First I don't know if attempting to cast to List or Collection is sufficient - are there are other types I should attempt to cast to? Are there any errors I shouldn't ignore?

How to do this right?

Comment: fyi Java does not support mixed match type in list as you have in `input`, it can be like `input = [[1],[2],[3,4], [5,6], [7]];`

Comment: and there could be `null` values there (exception handling is for what otherwise)?

Comment: I think you can do this `concatenated.addAll((Iterable) v);` instead of try to cast to both `Collection` and `List`.

Comment: @MrCholo An array list does not have an overload for `addAll` with `Iterable`. The simplest interface you can use is `Collection` [See here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)).  The reason being that `Iterable` doesn't have to persist the data. It can be a read once, or even random in what data is returned. All it specifies is that you can iterate on it.

Comment: This type of list operation is often called "flatten".

Comment: @Fax yes you're right, flatten or flatMap if you map

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The code doesn't need `Exception` handling as such unless there are `null` values in the lists. It should be sufficient though in your case to just cast basis of `instanceOf` as:

```
// Edit: Since the type of the input `Collection` is not bound strictly
List<Object> flatten(Collection<?> input) {
    List<Object> concatenated = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object v : input) {
        if (v instanceof Collection) {
            concatenated.addAll(flatten((Collection<?>) v));
        } else {
            concatenated.add(v);
        }
    }
    return concatenated;
}
```

using it further on jshell gives me this output:

```
jshell> List<Object> list = List.of(1,2,List.of(3,4),List.of(5,6),7) 
list ==> [1, 2, [3, 4], [5, 6], 7]

jshell> flatten(list)
$3 ==> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

:

Comment: yeah but what about Collection? Can you use instanceof on Iterable? Collection and List both implement Iterable, so that might work

Comment: There might be nulls in the lists, how do I handle that?

Comment: @MrCholo that depends on the list you're adding to, with an `ArrayList` as in the current solution, `null`s would be accepted as well.

Comment: @MrCholo `null` is a valid argument to `instanceof`. it will always return false. And an `ArrayList` can accept `null` as an input to `add`.

Comment: I think a nice addition to this solution would be to make it recursive. ie `concatenated.addAll(concatenateList((List<T>) v))` This way you can handle multiple levels of nesting. A better name on this method might be `flatten`

Comment: any reason why you are checking `v instanceof List` instead of `v instanceof Collection`?

Comment: @Kartik none, started off from a specific use-case.

Comment: @flakes yes flattening is good addition, but would overcomplicate the question which doesn't really involve that part

Comment: if `v` is a List instance, will it also be a Collection instance? I didn't expect that

Comment: @nullpointer I think assuming that the array is `Collection<T> input` is incorrect. OP is not using the collection as intended. Right now its a mixed set of classes. There are `T` elements and `Collection<T>` elements. Because of this misuse of the type system, I think you should just strip this to the non specialized format `Collection input`

Comment: @MrCholo `List` extends `Collection`

Comment: @flakes In my understanding keeping the type bound should avoid exception handling for a class cast at least. Hence would prefer to keep it instead of all raw types other wise.

Comment: @nullpointer even in the example you provided, you use `List<Object>` as the collection. `Collection<T>` doesn't add any value because `T` always has to be `Object` for any practical use of the method. If the input `T` was not `Object`, then the contract of the list has already been broken

Comment: At the very least, use `Collection<?>` as the input and `List<Object>` as the result.

Comment: @flakes the example provided could be using specific type as well `List<Integer> list = List.of(1,2,9,10,7)` or even `List<List<Integer>> list = List.of(List.of(1,2), List.of(3,4))` and it would still work. Why should it be required to specify an `Object` there? Also, I really don't see an output of `List` of `String` and `Integer` in the question as well.

Comment: Because the expected input to this method, say `List.of(1, List.of(2,3))`, is neither a `List<Integer>` or a `List<List<Integer>>`

Comment: Further, if the input was `List<List<Integer>>` then the output expected would be `List<List<Integer>>`, which is incorrect because the transformation changes it to `List<Integer>`. And if the input was already a flat `List<Integer>` there would be no point in calling the method at all

Comment: @flakes hmm, well I get the point of `List<List<Integer>>` input. Thanks. Just that now I might just try and find a better generic solution maybe.

Comment: @nullpointer It's an interesting problem! I have tried to solve this problem before (when dealing with examining JSON data without having a schema ahead of time) and I don't think Java has a good model for dealing with this. The root problem is that a basic `Collection` or `List` or `Map` interface does not account for nested hierarchies of data when specializing the container. Other languages combat this problem differently, say through the use of pattern matching rather than strict class matching. A good example of tackling this is in Python's new type hints system.

Answer (score 5):

As others have mentioned, using exceptions for control flow is not ideal. You can instead use the `instanceof` operator to test if an element is a `Collection`. The [answer by nullpointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54624386/6395627) shows a good example of this. If you want an more generic option you could also do something like:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public static <E> List<E> deepFlatten(final Iterable<?> iterable, final Class<E> type) {
    if (type.isPrimitive() || type.isArray() || Iterable.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "type must not denote a primitive, array, or java.lang.Iterable type: " + type);
    }
    final List<E> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final Object element : iterable) {

        if (element instanceof Iterable<?>) {
            result.addAll(deepFlatten((Iterable<?>) element, type)); // recursion

        } else if (element != null && element.getClass().isArray()) {

            if (element instanceof Object[]) {
                result.addAll(deepFlatten(Arrays.asList((Object[]) element), type)); // recursion
            } else { // primitive array
                final Iterable<?> itrArray = IntStream.range(0, Array.getLength(element))
                        .mapToObj(index -> Array.get(element, index))::iterator; // method reference
                result.addAll(deepFlatten(itrArray, type)); // recursion
            }

        } else {
            /*
             * Will throw ClassCastException if any element is not an instance
             * of "type". You could also throw a NullPointerException here if
             * you don't want to allow null elements.
             */
            result.add(type.cast(element));
        }

    }
    return result;
}
```

This also handles "embedded" arrays, as well as `Iterable`s, through recursion. Note it doesn't handle `Map`s because of the ambiguity; should we flatten the keys or the values—or both?

Calling the above with:

```
Iterable<?> iterable = List.of(
        "A", "B", "C", "D",
        List.of("E", "F", List.of("G", "H"), "I", "J"),
        "K",
        new String[]{"L", "M", "N", "O", "P"},
        new String[][]{{"Q", "R"}, {"S", "T"}, {"U"}, {"V"}},
        new Object[]{"W", "X"},
        "Y", "Z"
);
List<String> flattened = deepFlatten(iterable, String.class);
System.out.println(flattened);
```

Gave me:

```
[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z]
```

Note that the letters are in order because `List`s and arrays have guaranteed iteration orders. If your `Iterable` contained a `Set` the result of the `deepFlatten` may not be in the same order each time.

Answer (score 2):

Use of `Exceptions` to control application flow/business logic is an anti-pattern. You can read more about it [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729379/why-not-use-exceptions-as-regular-flow-of-control) and [here](http://wiki.c2.com/?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl).

Regarding storing different types of elements in Collections could be difficult to debug and maintain. You can write your own wrapper and encapsulate the handling of it from usage. You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117612/storing-different-types-of-elements-in-a-list-in-java) for an inspiration.