# Store objects of different types in an ArrayList

Tags: java

My App reads data from a csv file and store it in objects. My Load class have the method "load" for that purpose, it reads the csv and store its data divided in two objects and then group them in an ArrayList which is then returned by the method, the two objects that I'm referring to are:

A `Header object` to store only the headers of the csv (aka the first line of the csv).
A `List(ArrayList) of GameData objects` generated dynamically per each line of the csv.
Both objects are different, they have different fields and different methods.

```
             CSV
| Game  | Map      | Players | <--- Stored in a Header object      | 
| ========================== |                                     | Want to store both 
| Game1 | Panguea  | 6       | <--- | Stored in an ArrayList       | the Header and the ArrayList
| Game2 | Panguea  | 8       | <--- | containing the three objects | in a new ArrayList.
| Game3 | Medium   | 12      | <--- |                              |
```

The problem here is **I can't put two different type objects into the same ArrayList** and I would like to know how to do that (or if it is even possible) because I want the "load" method to returns a single ArrayList so I can use it for other functionalities, for example I have a `Printer class` which have a method that prints the object that is passed into it.

This is the method that do the job:

```
public List<GameData> load(){
// List for store the data which is brought by the scanner
        mainView = new ArrayList<>();

// Scanner eluded for clarity

// Get the headers 
        String[] tableHeader = scanner.nextLine().split("\\t");
        headerFields = new Headers(tableHeader);
        mainView.add(headerFields);    

// Get the rest of the data
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            try{
                String[] elements = scanner.nextLine().split("\\t");
                mainView.add(new GameData(some params...);
            }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
        return mainView;
    }
```

- I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117612/storing-different-types-of-elements-in-a-list-in-java) but I don't like it because then I will have an empty interface just for the sake of group things since I can't see a compelling reason to create new methods in it.
- I also don't like the Object solution because then I will need to cast the types every time I want to return the objects inside the List.
- Another solution would be that Header Class extends GameData class, that way I can put a Header object inside a GameData ArrayList, but it doesn't seem right to me because Header doesn't need any field or method from GameData so the inheritance would be only for that specific operation.

PD: I can't use just one object to store all the data because the headers(first line of csv) are all Strings while the rest of the lines in the csv contain a mixture of String and int values. Also structure wise it doesn't make sense because then every object would have those headers and it will be redundant because those objects already have fields with the same name.

Comment: The only option to store in the same array list is to use `Object`. Instead create a new class that will have `Headers` as member and a list of `GameData` as member.

Comment: Not sure if it fits your use case, but I found it cleaner when working with csv's to use a 3'rd party library like 4 e.g. org.apache.commons.csv.
Helps separate concerns. From what I recall it allows to read in headers in the first line, then the rest of the content in the rest.

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be to create a new class, which will store the Object and the class.
Here is an untested example:

```
class ClassObject
{
 public final Class<?> type;
 public final Object instance;
 public ClassObject(Class<?> type, Object instance)
 {
  this.type = type;
  this.instance = instance;
 }
}
```

Now you can make a List of ClassObject

```
ArrayList<ClassObject> foo;
```

And if you want to access some class you can do the following:

```
switch(foo.get(i).type)
{
case ClassOne.class:
 //stuff with (ClassOne)foo.get(i).instance
 break;
case ClassTwo.class:
 //stuff with (ClassTwo)foo.get(i).instance
 break;
 //etc...
}
```

But this is just an idea. I'm sure there are better solutions.

Comment: How is this better then using `ArrayList<Object>` and `instanceof`?

Comment: @Oleg It isn't. But for some reason the asker doesn't want to use ArrayList<Object>, so this is an alternative. Also, you can use this with switch|case so you won't have to add an if statement for every possible class.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like the "Header" object and "GameData" objects and always going to be used together. What if you made a "Games" object which had

- a "labels" instance variable of type ArrayList
- a "games" instance variable of type ArrayList

and return this entire object? Its been a minute but I'm pretty sure you could create a private class that would actually make your code a little more readable.

Comment: I don't know if I'm understanding it correctly but you say that it will be better if instead of have two Classes (Headers and GamesData) I should have one Class (Game) that will have the required fields to then create two instances for labels and games with the corresponding data? The problem I see with that is the GamesData Class already have fields with the name of the headers so if I combine the fields of GamesData and Headers in one Class (Game) it will be redundant, right?

Comment: That's correct, in this case you can ditch the Headers class and just go with the headers instance which is an ArrayList of type String