# Adding new Parent Objects to ExpandableRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, generics, android-recyclerview, expandablerecyclerview

I am using [ExpandableRecyclerView](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view) in my project to have a nested RecyclerView. It works great, except when you need to dynamically update the parent list.

My project have `Product` class as parent object (and extended `ParentListItem`). I am getting the list of Products from an API and thus need to clear the current list and add the List I have got.

In the ExpandableRecyclerAdapter I've tried this method -

```
public void onDataChanged(ArrayList<Product> parentObjects) {
    this.getParentItemList().clear();
    this.getParentItemList().addAll(parentObjects);

    this.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, parentObjects.size() - 1);
}
```

However it's giving a strange generic error

```
Error:(60, 33) error: no suitable method found for addAll(ArrayList<Product>)
method List.addAll(Collection<? extends CAP#1>) is not applicable
(actual argument ArrayList<Product> cannot be converted to Collection<? extends CAP#1> by method invocation conversion)
method List.addAll(int,Collection<? extends CAP#1>) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method Collection.addAll(Collection<? extends CAP#1>) is not applicable
(actual argument ArrayList<Product> cannot be converted to Collection<? extends CAP#1> by method invocation conversion)
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
CAP#1 extends ParentListItem from capture of ? extends ParentListItem
```

The parentItemList is of type `List<? extends ParentListItem>`, so according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407995/lists-with-wildcards-cause-generic-voodoo-error), it's not possible to add anything to the existing list and since there's no setter present, I can't replace the complete list too.

I have tried creating a new `ExpandableRecyclerAdapter` object and setting it as a new adapter for RecyclerView. Although it worked, but I don't think that's a good way to replace whole adapter whenever there's a new data coming.

So is there any other way to update the parent object list, either in one go or one by one?

Comment: I am also facing exactly same problem. Did  u got any solution for above issue?

Comment: I too have this problem.

Comment: It seems that the answer might be here: https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view/issues/185