# Generics: Upper Bounded Wildcards conversion/casting error

Tags: java, generics, functional-programming

Here is the test:

```
@Test
public void genericsTest() {
    String s = "x";
    List<? extends String> strings = singletonList(s);
    Optional<Function<String, List<? extends String>>> optionalSelector = Optional.empty();
    optionalSelector.map(selector -> selector.apply(s)).orElse(strings);
}
```

And here is the error:

```
java: incompatible types: java.util.List<capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.String> cannot be converted to java.util.List<capture#2 of ? extends java.lang.String>
```

Of course, it can be fixed using the raw type trick.

```
    optionalSelector.map(selector -> selector.apply(s)).orElse((List)strings);
```

But I'd like to understand the cause of this error.

**Update**:

It's not a duplicate of [Lists with wildcards cause Generic voodoo error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407995/lists-with-wildcards-cause-generic-voodoo-error) which is about adding into an upper-bounded wildcard list; this topic is also well described in [Wildcard Guidelines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html).

In my case I'm not trying to add something into the list as you can see above.

Also, the error messages are different.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be something wrong with the multiple levels of type inference here. With this line:

```
optionalSelector.map(selector -> selector.apply(s)).orElse(strings);
```

With the call to `map`, you're attempting to convert the original `Optional<Function<String, List<? extends String>>>` to a `Optional<List<? extends String>>`.  Then, with `orElse`, you're attempting to convert that to a `List<? extends String>`.  It seems reasonable.

I can get it to compile without resorting to casting to raw types, by giving the intermediate step an explicit type.

```
Optional<List<? extends String>> intermedSelector = optionalSelector.map(selector -> selector.apply(s));
intermedSelector.orElse(strings);
```

This shows that if the compiler can infer the result of the call to `map` to be a `Optional<List<? extends String>>`, then the call to `orElse` will compile.

However, I can change the explicit type to something where the declaration of `intermedSelector` compiles, but the call to `orElse` does not compile.  I've changed the explicit type of `interMedSelector` from `Optional<List<? extends String>>` to `Optional<? extends List<? extends String>>`, with an added `? extends`.

```
Optional<? extends List<? extends String>> intermedSelector = optionalSelector.map(selector -> selector.apply(s));
intermedSelector.orElse(strings);
```

The error here is similar to the one you're getting:

```
J.java:26: error: incompatible types: List<CAP#1> cannot be converted to CAP#2
    List<? extends String> result = intermedSelector.orElse(strings);
                                                            ^
  where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
    CAP#1 extends String from capture of ? extends String
    CAP#2 extends List<? extends String> from capture of ? extends List<? extends String>
```

With your code, the compiler must be inferring something unexpected, yet related to, `Optional<List<? extends String>>`.  I can't tell if the compiler's captured type is `Optional<? extends List<? extends String>>` or something else, but that appears to be why you're getting the error.

My solution

```
Optional<List<? extends String>> intermedSelector = optionalSelector.map(selector -> selector.apply(s));
intermedSelector.orElse(strings);
```

can be expressed in one statement, if I supply the proper type parameter to the call to `map`, so the compiler doesn't infer something unexpected.

```
optionalSelector.<List<? extends String>>map(selector -> selector.apply(s)).orElse(strings);
```